# Raspbmc only responds to bluetooth keyboard after restart

Tags: raspbmc, kodi, bluetooth

So I managed to pair this bluetooth keyboard with my raspberry pi running Raspbmc. However, when I turn my keyboard back on, I cannot use it inside XBMC. The keyboard is paired with the Raspberry, but XBMC is not responding to my keystrokes.

If I drop to the console, the keyboard works perfectly. When I leave the console and XBMC restarts, the keyboard starts working in XBMC.

Basically, my keyboard needs to be connected before starting XBMC before it works.

Is there some way for XBMC to pick up on the connecting of a Bluetooth keyboard after it has started?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an exact answer to your question but just another alternative way of controlling your raspbmc server. I personally use my phone and tablets running android to control it. You could also enable http connection through the web browser. Find out what the IP address of your pi is and type it into your browser once you've enabled this setting and you can use the remote on screen.

Yatse works well with android. The XBMC app for android was not working for me:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.leetzone.android.yatsewidgetfree

For an iphone, the regular stock xmbc app should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, but as you said, this doesn't really answer my question :)

Answer (score -1):

see http://trac.xbmc.org/ticket/14028
it's a bug, or was (?) a bug

Comment: This may well be the cause of the problem, But to avoid link rot your answer should summarize the pertinent points (what version does this effect), and what if any workarounds exist (will an upgrade to a specific version solve the problem).